# HTML form input field with comma separated

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to figure out how to take multiple word input in a single text box in a form with each word separated by comma(,) and then paring the word based on comma and inserting into db as each word as separate record.

what I thought of is taking the input

and then using explode function of php for separating out the words, and store in db, but I am not sure how to store in db.

Comment: i have a form page with input as text field, and i am storing that input value in a variabla , then i am using explode to separate out the values based on comma, after then  i am lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know a bunch of mysql_* function answers are going to come in, so ill add the prepared query route.

This isn't flawless, but you'll get the idea

```
// Get the array of words
$words = explode( ',', $formname );

// Create an array of :word1, :word2, :word3, etc for use in binding
foreach( range( 1, count( $words ) ) as $wordnumber ) {
    $bind[] = ':word'.$wordnumber;
}

// Create the sql query
$sql = sprintf( "insert into table ( word ) values ( %s )", implode( '),(', $bind ) );

// Prepare the query
$stmnt = $pdo->prepare( $sql );

// Bind each word
foreach( $words as $k => $word ) {
    $stmnt->bindValue( ":word" . ++$k, $word );
}

// Execute
$stmnt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with PDO too:

```
<?php 
//Connect safely to your database
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server. Details:'.$e->getMessage());
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST['words'])) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO words_table (word) VALUES (:word)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':word', $word);

    foreach (explode(',', $_POST['words']) as $word) {
        $word = trim($word);
        if (empty($word)) {
            continue;
        }
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
//Your form
?>
<h1>Words</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="words"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encapsulate the words in quotes, this should do the trick:

```
<?php

$myString='sometext,someothertext,and something else';
$query="insert into table1 (columnName) values (('".str_replace(',',"'),('",$myString)."'))";

echo $query;
?>
```

Output:

```
insert into table1 (columnName) values (('sometext'),('someothertext'),('and something else'))
```

This will insert multiple records in proper accordance with the [mysql insert multiple values syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Comment: but it will not stored the diffrent word as diff records, ex. aditya,laurence,max,raptor this should enter as separate record for each word.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = $_POST['words'];
$piece = explode(',',$str);
foreach($piece as $substr){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (words) VALUES ('".$substr."');";
}
```

Comment: While this will work, you can do what Aditya Kumar asks, it can be done with a single query using multiple insert values - which would be much more efficient.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to it?